# What does character choice affect?

Tags: far-cry-2

At the start of the game, you can choose from a range of characters to play as. What does this affect though?

The selection screen only shows you bios and some stats like age and height; it's not clear if these have any effect on the game.

I did notice that some characters that you could have picked at the start become buddies, so one effect might be to change who your buddies eventually are, and all the consequences that entails.

Does it affect anything else though? Your stats? How NPCs treat you? The story?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Character selection will only impact which buddies are available (you can't be a buddy to yourself, for example) and the order in which they appear.  Each buddy also has different side quests available, so if you pick a specific character you won't get 'asked' to do those missions.

Far Cry 2 Wiki example: http://farcry.wikia.com/wiki/Marty_Alencar